# db_creator role missing in SQL Server 2014 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

My apologies if this question betrays my inexperience.

I am attempting to create a utility C# app to backup and restore a local database. The app uses a connection string that specifies a username and password; the user belongs to the `db_owner` role.

Backing up works, but restore does not. The user does not have permission to restore. I used SQL Server Management Studio 2014 to see if I could add the user to the `db_creator` role, but the role is not available.

What are possible explanations for the `db_creator` role missing? Can the role be created or added again?

Comment: That you're saying that the user belongs to db_owner suggests that you might be looking in the wrong place. db_owner is a database-level role while dbcreator is a server-level role. Have you checked at the server-level to see if that role exists?

Comment: @Ben Thul:  Thank you very much! I was indeed looking in the wrong place.